# Why can't I change the Primary DNS Suffix on my laptop?

Tags: windows-10

I bought a Windows 10 home edition laptop from my school, and when I reached home I noticed my Primary DNS Suffix was "DELIA.DGOS". Even when I'm at home. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0wNi.png)

So, I tried changing it via the Control Panel, but after a restart, it says the same. I even tried changing the registry key value of: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DNSRegisteredAdapters\WifiCardID\PrimaryDomainName`

But after a restart, it changes back. I don't want my laptop name to end with this DNS suffix. How do I change it? Is it hard-coded into the wifi card?

I ran several commands to determine it:

```
>wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration get caption, DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
Caption                                              DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
[00000000] Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
[00000001] Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz          {"DELIA.DGOS"}
[00000002] Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
[00000003] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
[00000004] Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
[00000005] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
[00000006] WAN Miniport (SSTP)
[00000007] WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
[00000008] WAN Miniport (L2TP)
[00000009] WAN Miniport (PPTP)
[00000010] WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
[00000011] WAN Miniport (IP)
[00000012] WAN Miniport (IPv6)
[00000013] WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)

>wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration get caption, DNSDomain
Caption                                              DNSDomain
[00000000] Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
[00000001] Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
[00000002] Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (6) I219-V
[00000003] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
[00000004] Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
[00000005] Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
[00000006] WAN Miniport (SSTP)
[00000007] WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
[00000008] WAN Miniport (L2TP)
[00000009] WAN Miniport (PPTP)
[00000010] WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
[00000011] WAN Miniport (IP)
[00000012] WAN Miniport (IPv6)
[00000013] WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
```

Comment: Do a TCP / IP Reset: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer and test the DNS

Comment: @John No it doesn't work, running ipconfig /all in cmd shows the same primary DNS suffix. I have a feeling it is burned into the wifi card.

Comment: I have not seen a wireless card embed DNS. Perhaps uninstall the Wireless card, restart and let Windows install the card with its driver

Comment: @John Ok, sure.

Comment: @John Nope it doesn't work, even when using Microsoft drivers, the Dns Suffix is "DELIA.DGOS" I don't know how the manufacturer even did this.

Comment: Try a USB Wireless Card. I suggest that. Otherwise you may need to do a fresh install of Windows 10.

Comment: @John Yeah I have used a USB wifi adapter with no problem, maybe I will just do the fresh install of Windows. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I post an answer with this information , would you find it helpful?

Comment: @John Yeah sure. Just a side note all students' laptops in the school have this DNS suffix.

Comment: Thanks and good luck with the new card

Comment: Also - just a note:  The DNS issue was probably built somehow into the School Image that you used. This is why other school laptops have the same issue.

Comment: @John No, I am a student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

1. Do a TCP / IP Reset: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt Then: ipconfig /flushdns Then: restart the computer and test the DNS
2. Try re-installing the wireless card.

Then, 3. If these regular solutions do not work, then try a USB Wireless card as that should work

Comment: I fixed my issue, I simply changed the value of two registry keys namely, `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain` and `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\NVDomain` to blank. You can edit your answer to help others with the same issue!

Comment: That is good to know. I am quite sure the Windows Image used was responsible for this. Native (Retail) Windows images from Microsoft do not do this. Still thanks for posting this.

Comment: No problem. My pleasure